# how to get text out of 'a' tags in python using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

```
<div class="breadcrumbs pt10 pb10">
<a>Location :</a> 
"National Harbor                    ,
                Maryland" 
<br>
<a href="#" class="type">Venue : </a>
"Gaylord National Resort & Convention Center "
</div>
```

How to get text National Harbor, Maryland, Gaylord National Resort & Convention Center from above in python using scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [scrapy selectors](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)

To achieve what you want for all anchor tags on the page you can use:

```
link_text_list = response.selector.xpath('//a/text()').extract()
```

Comment: i applied this code.."response.selector.xpath('//div[@class="breadcrumbs pt10 pb10"]/a/text()').extract()"....But o/p i'm getting like this.."[u'Location :', u'Venue : ']"

Comment: @surfer190..can you please give me reply for above one..?

Comment: The `u` in front of the string means `unicode`. This is probably `python 2.7` best to use python `3.6`